# Sorting multiple columns, with the second column being sorted by numerical order

Tags: sort

file: nameslist.txt

```
Emily 0
Emily 1
Emily 5
Joe 0
Joe 10
Joe 5
Joe 6
```

This is the command I ran:

```
cat nameslist.txt | sort -k1 -k2
```

The result:

```
Emily 0
Emily 1
Emily 5
Joe 0
Joe 10
Joe 5
Joe 6
```

It looks like it's sorting by the first number, but how can I get the second column to sort numerically?  The result I want is:

```
Emily 0
Emily 1
Emily 5
Joe 0
Joe 5
Joe 6
Joe 10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `-n` option to sort numerically:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2n nameslist.txt
```

There is no need to use `cat` to read the input file.  `sort` will do that without needing another process.

The `-k1,1` notation sets the start and stop limits of the first sort key to the first field.